# Nasm : how to use ORG directive when you want debug symbol too?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm, elf

This question is partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369717/how-to-generate-gdb-symbol-file-with-nasm)  but they don't help with generating elf file with ORG directive when you are obliged to use it.

I need a way to combine nasm use and ORG directive to produce an equivalent Elf file.
This is how I proceed now:

```
nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g Main.s -o Main.elf
```

but nasm keeps rejecting it because of my necessary ORG.

Comment: `org` directives really do not make a lot of sense with ELF.  What are you trying to achieve?  Can you show us your code?

Comment: Org applies to the -f bin` option. If you want to set an origin point you'll have to use a linker script or override the linker command line with something like -Ttext=0xNNNNNNNN where NNNNNNNN is the origin point of the  code.

Comment: Is this for a kernel / OSDev?

Comment: yes. It is from a piece of code from OSDev. Thank you @MichaelPetch, it is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to give a precise solution to your problem, in case others would be in the same situation:

If you want to set your binary origin to 0x7c00 (as in common kernel boot-loader)

```
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat binary -o Main.bin Main.elf
```