# Watch nasm variables in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nasm

I've followed [this link](https://github.com/newtonsart/vscode-assembly) to set up
nasm debugging in VS Code on Linux. It is working fine, register values are getting updated when I'm stepping through the code.

I would like to display user defined variables in the watch window and have them updated as I step through the code. So, if I have

```
section .data
     hello db 'Hello, World!',0
```

I would like to see this variable in the watch window, the same way I, for example, see user defined array variables when writing a C program. I have tried googling the solution and asked ChatGPT but didn't find any solution. I've tried to add it in multiple ways: `hello`, `hello, <length>`, `hello[length]` but every time it is displayed `hello:<blank>`.

Is this possible? Also, please don't recommend alternatives like SASM, I would like to use VS Code only, if possible.

Edit:
Started gdb from cmd and got:

`info variables` : variable listed under non-debugging symbols (other ones being `__bss_start`, `_edata`, `_end`)

`info symbol <name>` : `<name>` has unknown type; cast it to its declared type

`info symbol (char[])<name>` : evaluation requires the program to have a function `malloc`

`info symbol (char*)<name>`: no symbol matches `(char*)<name>`

`info symbol <address>`: `<name>` in section `.data` of `<program path>` (same thing with `*(char*)<address>`)

`info symbol *(char*)<name>`: cannot access memory address  (different address than the one listed on `info variables`)

Comment: for the debugger `hello` is just a void pointer, it has no type, maybe `*((char*)hello)`

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I've tried that one as well but it still displays the same.

Comment: what does gdb show for `hello` and `(char*)hello`

Comment: For both of them (and the other ones) just what is written, colon and then blank space after, ie (char*)hello: <blank space>.

Comment: does the debugger know the symbol `hello`, does it show the address of the symbol

Comment: In the watch window, no. If I load the address of the message to one of the registers, register is displaying the hex address.

Comment: but that happens because the assembler and linker/loader have hard coded the hex address in the `mov` instruction, if you put `(char*)ff405060` in the watch window, does the watch window work at all when using gdb for assembler, can you define debug symbols in an assembler file to be added to the exe file

Comment: It's the same thing. Still blank, even if I add hex address casted to char* to watch window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490067/9938317 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63746240/9938317 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17399314/9938317

Comment: These answers provide tips I've already tried but I followed them to make sure I didn't miss anything. I was suspecting too that this might be something related to debugging symbols. I also enabled debuginfod in gdbinit but still no luck. Do you think that a VS Code extension could be written for this issue?

Comment: gdb can handle separate symbol files, but I was unable to find its format, You have to study the ELF, COFF, GDB tool source code, too much work for me. What symbols did nasm generate?

Comment: I've edited the original post to include a response to this question. Also, I wasn't asking for your help to write it, I was wondering if it would be doable, at least in theory.

Comment: I'm not going to write it but was wondering why it is difficult to get a **description** of the COFF and ELF file formats, they would contain description of the debug symbols

Comment: Here's food for thought: I've created a new project with makefile only (no vscode json files for building and running) and used makefile tools extension. I got the watch window to display the array variable using: (char*)<address>, <length>. It displayed all values as I wanted, one below the other with array indices. Unfortunately, the program itself was wasn't working properly so I changed the makefile without saving it. Currently, the debugger is not working at all, I need to re-create it but I know it is working in principle.

Comment: what are you doing different in the makefile compared to the vsc task json file, you can call the makefile from the task

Comment: No difference, when I compare compile and link commands from json files and makefile. In the makefile project, settings.json was created automatically by VS Code, it has a "makefile.launchConfigurations" property and, in it, "cwd", "binary path" and "binaryArgs" fields. I'm thinking that makefile tools extension does something in the background that json-only project doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a sleepless night, I think I finally found the solution. One disclaimer, I've switched to AT&T syntax (GAS), I like it more.

I've created a new VS Code project, installed Makefile tools extension, created a source file `sample.s` and a following makefile:

```
AS = as
LD = ld

ASFLAGS = -g --64 --gstabs

TARGET = sample
SRC = sample.s

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SRC)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $(TARGET).o $(SRC)
    $(LD) -m elf_x86_64 -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).o

.PHONY: clean run

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGET).o

run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)
```

In the makefile tools extension, `build target` is set to `all` and `launch target` is set to `sample`.

After placing the breakpoint and running the debugger, I put the variable to the `watch window` in the following format:

```
(char*)0x402000, 15
```

where the `0x402000` is the address of symbol. Lenght is less than 15 but it doesn't matter.

In this way, the whole array is displayed, with its values and indices. I've also tried to change one of the values in the array and it gets updated and displayed properly.

@rioV8 Thank you very much for your help.